# Build MFP Cordova with android studio : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.cordova.Whitelist$URLPattern

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have an issue with a MobileFirst Cordova project, when I build it with android studio it works on terminal with android version above 5.0 but for android version < 5.0 i have this issue :

```
03-16 10:49:29.591 18948-18948/com.ibm.scana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.ibm.scana, PID: 18948
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.cordova.Whitelist$URLPattern
       at org.apache.cordova.Whitelist.addWhiteListEntry(Whitelist.java:137)
       at org.apache.cordova.ConfigXmlParser.parse(ConfigXmlParser.java:86)
       at org.apache.cordova.ConfigXmlParser.parse(ConfigXmlParser.java:75)
       at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadConfig(CordovaActivity.java:236)
       at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onCreate(CordovaActivity.java:206)
       at com.ibm.scana.CordovaApp.onCreate(CordovaApp.java:18)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to change compileSdkVersion & buildToolsVersion but it still does not work.

Comment: what is your  android version throwing this error ? please provide exactly version .

Comment: What alterations did you do to your project? Such as: targetSDK, compileSDK, minSDK. Also, are you doing a Gradle build or an Ant build? Can you provide reproduction steps?

Comment: I try to change targetSDK, compileSDK, minSDK and I have already the same issue. My build is a gradle build.

Comment: Are you able to provide reproduction steps with a new application?

Answer (score 1):

Update: @Idan, Yes We follow that guide which is from your email. but still doest works. Here is how we finally fix it: 1. in android manifest file add android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in application tab 2. in build.gradle add this compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Please note that is problem only for android 4.4.2 which is the sdk19

Thanks and have a great day